# How to set the timeout for provider http RPC requests in the ethers

Tags: ethers.js, json-rpc, time

I am using JsonRpcProvider in ethers V6. I am sending requests to node like getBlocknumber, getBalance ,sendTransaction etc through JsonRpcProvider. I want to set the **response timeout** for the requests I send to the node through the provider.

I have found and tried many methods but all of them failed. Doing it in ethers V5 and V6 is also fine. can you please advise me.

Answer (score 1):

There is `timeout` parameter in `ConnectionInfo` object.
According to https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/web/#ConnectionInfo

Have You tried manipulating it?

```
const provider = new JsonRpcProvider(rpcUrl);

provider._getConnection().timeout = 600;
```

Since requests are then send using this `_getConnection()` response object. Default is 5 minutes.

Comment: I already tried this method: I set the **timeout to 10 (milliseconds)** and tested it by calling **provider.getBlocknumber()**. I expected to get a timeout error, but it worked fine. This method did not solve the problem

Comment: I try it again on ethers V5. Your method seems to work fine for timeout in V5, but not in V6..